# Understanding the Spring MVC's DeferredResult class in the context of the spring-mvc-chat github application

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, asynchronous

I am trying to better understand how the following spring mvc 3.2 application works: https://github.com/rstoyanchev/spring-mvc-chat

My question is about the [deferredResult Spring MVC class](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/request/async/DeferredResult.html). I noticed that at a given time there are as many entries in the `chatRequests` Map as there are users connected to the chat application.

Say there are **3 users connected** to the chat application. You will see that when **user #3 posts a message** (see postMessage method below), then **the for loop (in postMessage method) iterates three times**. I can't figure out why that is.

I am including sample code below.

Code for controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/mvc/chat")
public class ChatController {

    private final ChatRepository chatRepository;
    private final Map<DeferredResult<List<String>>, Integer> chatRequests = new ConcurrentHashMap<DeferredResult<List<String>>, Integer>();

    @Autowired
    public ChatController(ChatRepository chatRepository) {
        this.chatRepository = chatRepository;
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public DeferredResult<List<String>> getMessages(@RequestParam int messageIndex) {

        final DeferredResult<List<String>> deferredResult = new DeferredResult<List<String>>(null, Collections.emptyList());
        this.chatRequests.put(deferredResult, messageIndex);

        deferredResult.onCompletion(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                chatRequests.remove(deferredResult);
            }
        });

        List<String> messages = this.chatRepository.getMessages(messageIndex);
        if (!messages.isEmpty()) {
            deferredResult.setResult(messages);
        }

        return deferredResult;
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public void postMessage(@RequestParam String message) {

        this.chatRepository.addMessage(message);

        // Update all chat requests as part of the POST request
        // See Redis branch for a more sophisticated, non-blocking approach

        for (Entry<DeferredResult<List<String>>, Integer> entry : this.chatRequests.entrySet()) {
            List<String> messages = this.chatRepository.getMessages(entry.getValue());
            entry.getKey().setResult(messages);
        }
    }
}
```

Javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    function ChatViewModel() {

        var that = this;

        that.userName = ko.observable('');
        that.chatContent = ko.observable('');
        that.message = ko.observable('');
        that.messageIndex = ko.observable(0);
        that.activePollingXhr = ko.observable(null);


        var keepPolling = false;

        that.joinChat = function() {
            if (that.userName().trim() != '') {
                keepPolling = true;
                pollForMessages();
            }
        }

        function pollForMessages() {
            if (!keepPolling) {
                return;
            }
            var form = $("#joinChatForm");


            that.activePollingXhr($.ajax({url: form.attr("action"), type: "GET", data: form.serialize(), cache: false,
                success: function(messages) {
                    console.log(messages);
                    for (var i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
                        that.chatContent(that.chatContent() + messages[i] + "\n");
                        that.messageIndex(that.messageIndex() + 1);
                    }
                },
                error: function(xhr) {
                    if (xhr.statusText != "abort" && xhr.status != 503) {
                        resetUI();
                        console.error("Unable to retrieve chat messages. Chat ended.");
                    }
                },
                complete: pollForMessages
            }));
            $('#message').focus();
        }

        that.postMessage = function() {
            if (that.message().trim() != '') {
                var form = $("#postMessageForm");
                $.ajax({url: form.attr("action"), type: "POST",
                    data: "message=[" + that.userName() + "] " + $("#postMessageForm input[name=message]").val(),
                    error: function(xhr) {
                        console.error("Error posting chat message: status=" + xhr.status + ", statusText=" + xhr.statusText);
                    }
                });
                that.message('');
            }
        }

        that.leaveChat = function() {
            that.activePollingXhr(null);
            resetUI();
            this.userName('');
        }

        function resetUI() {
            keepPolling = false;
            that.activePollingXhr(null);
            that.message('');
            that.messageIndex(0);
            that.chatContent('');
        }

    }

    //Activate knockout.js
    ko.applyBindings(new ChatViewModel());

});
```

and html page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title>Chat</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Chat</h1>

    <form id="joinChatForm" th:action="@{/mvc/chat}" data-bind="visible: activePollingXhr() == null">
        <p>
            <label for="user">User: </label>
            <input id="user" name="user" type="text" data-bind="value: userName"/>
            <input name="messageIndex" type="hidden" data-bind="value: messageIndex"/>
            <button id="start" type="submit" data-bind="click: joinChat">Join Chat</button>
        </p>
    </form>

    <form id="leaveChatForm" th:action="@{/mvc/chat}" data-bind="visible: activePollingXhr() != null">
        <p>
            You're chatting as <strong data-bind="text: userName"></strong>
            <button id="leave" type="submit" data-bind="click: leaveChat">Leave Chat</button>
        </p>
    </form>

    <div data-bind="visible: activePollingXhr() != null">
        <textarea rows="15" cols="60" readonly="readonly" data-bind="text: chatContent"></textarea>
    </div>

    <form id="postMessageForm" th:action="@{/mvc/chat}" data-bind="visible: activePollingXhr() != null">
        <p>
            <input id="message" name="message" type="text" data-bind="value: message" />
            <button id="post" type="submit" data-bind="click: postMessage">Post</button>
        </p>
    </form>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../../resources/js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js" th:src="@{/resources/js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../../resources/js/knockout-2.0.0.js" th:src="@{/resources/js/knockout-2.0.0.js}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../../resources/js/chat.js" th:src="@{/resources/js/chat.js}"></script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I discussed this topic at length with the author of Spring's DeferredResult class and here is the relevant part of our conversation:

To quote Rossen Stoyanchev:

> Roughly speaking. A DeferredResult is associated with an open request.
>   When the request completes, the DeferredResult is removed from the
>   map, and then, the client issues a new long polling request, which
>   adds a new DeferredResult instance

Comment: Well, I guess if you discussed this with the author of `DeferredResult` then you should place the entire communication some place. So that everyone gets to know more about it.

Comment: I think [this set of slides](http://rstoyanchev.github.io/spring-mvc-32-update/#8) from Rossen Stoyanchev throws some light on the topic as well.

Answer (score 11):

In order to understand what DeferredResult is doing you need to understand Servlet 3.0 Async concept.

Using Servlet 3.0 you can take AsyncContext from request, store it in kind of Collection.

```
AsyncContext aCtx = request.startAsync(request, response);
```

as the result your Application Container Thread will be released.

Make some operation on separate thread and write result back to the Servlet response:

```
aCtx.getResponse().getWriter().print(result);
```

From that point of your `DeferredResult` works absolutely the same.

Small example:

Now consider that every 5 second you're getting a quote from third party service. 
And you have clients which are long polling your server every in order to get updated what.

You Have your Controller method:

```
   /** put deferred result to some HashSet. This is the same logic as you 
         store async context in servlet 3.0, those are clients who are waiting for             
         response
    **/
    @RequestMapping(value="/getQuote.do", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public DeferredResult<String> getQuote(){
       final DeferredResult<String> deferredResult = new DeferredResult<String>();

       someMap.put(deferredResult);
       return deferredResult;
    }
```

now let's see the method outside of controller which gets quote and returns response to the client.

```
function getQuoteAndUpdateClients(){ 

      String quote = getUpdatedQuoteFromThirdPartyService();

      for (DeferredResult<String> deferredResult: someMap){
              deferredResult.setResult(quote);
       }
 }
```

Comment: Hi Danny. Thanks for your reply. However, my question was rather about a specific point in the provided code i.e. see this part of my post:  _Say there are 3 users connected to the chat application. You will see that when user #3 posts a message (see postMessage method below), then the for loop (in postMessage method) iterates three times. I can't figure out why that is._

Answer (score 1):

When a client connects a DeferredResult is stored for that client in this.chatRequests. When a client posts a message, it loops through all DeferredResults (read clients) to set a result. It is only logical that that happens 3 times when there are 3 clients connected.