# Spring MVC InterceptorHandler called twice with DeferredResult

Tags: java, spring-mvc

When I am using custom `HandlerInterceptor` and my controller returns `DeferredResult`, the  `preHandle` method of my custom interceptor called twice on each request. Consider a toy example.

My custom interceptor:

```
public class MyInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptor {
    static int i = 0;

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(i++);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, ModelAndView modelAndView) throws Exception {
    }

    @Override
    public void afterCompletion(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, Exception ex) throws Exception {
    }
}
```

My Spring Java configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class ApplicationConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(new MyInterceptor());
    }
}
```

My Controller:

```
@Controller
public class MyController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public DeferredResult<String> test() {
        DeferredResult<String> df = new DeferredResult<String>();
        df.setResult("blank");
        return df;
    }
}
```

So, on each page load I see two outputs from `preHandle` method. However, if I modify `MyController` in order to return just "blank" template (instead of `DeferredResult` with "blank" template), I see just one output from `preHandle` on each page load.

So, my question is why `preHandle` called twice when I use `DeferredResult` and is it possible to avoid this?

Comment: see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15357990/understanding-the-spring-mvcs-deferredresult-class-in-the-context-of-the-spring) which has the behaviour explained in detail.

Comment: @JavaBond can you please provide some more details, since I've not figured out explanation from that post.

Comment: quoting from the [accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15384965/1910582) `Roughly speaking. A DeferredResult is associated with an open request. When the request completes, the DeferredResult is removed from the map, and then, the client issues a new long polling request, which adds a new DeferredResult instance` which means a fresh request is issued by client to which the `DeferredResult` is attached as response. Which in turn explains why you have two interceptor invocations for every request. Let me know if you need further explanations.

Comment: I want to read HTTP Post and Remove the SOAP Tags and simply pass the XML data to Rest endpoint, is that possible ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to use `org.springframework.web.servlet.AsyncHandlerInterceptor`:

```
public interface AsyncHandlerInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptor {

    void afterConcurrentHandlingStarted(
            HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler)
            throws Exception;

}
```

**Spring MVC** execute sequence:

```
preHandle
afterConcurrentHandlingStarted
preHandle
postHandle
afterCompletion
```

Comment: I could not get the `afterConcurrentHandlingStarted` method to run. My app would not execute the code but would execute the `preHandle`.

Comment: When is the handler called here ? Between `preHandle` and 
`afterConcurrentHandlingStarted` in that order ?

Answer (score 17):

The difference between the two invocations can be seen by examining the value of [request.getDispatcherType()](http://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/javadoc/7.1.2.Final/javax/servlet/DispatcherType.html).

Answer (score 11):

I followed what [@thunder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3438692/thunder) mentioned by checking the value of `request.getDispatcherType()` and this worked for me.

```
public class MyInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, 
                             HttpServletResponse response,
                             Object handler) throws Exception {
        // NOTE: For all dispatchers that are not "REQUEST" like "ERROR", do
        // an early return which prevents the preHandle function from
        // running multiple times
        if (request.getDispatcherType() != DispatcherType.REQUEST) {
            return true;
        }
        // ... do other stuff and then do a final return
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not check for the actualy DispatchType? `request.getDispatcherType() != DispatcherType.REQUEST`

Comment: you must compare strings with equal method, not !=

Comment: getDispatcherType() returns an enum, there's no need to call name() and then compare the Strings. I would go with @xxtesaxx 's suggestion.

Answer (score 5):

As I'm exploring adding filter and Interceptor, I'm prettry sure that's caused by async calling. You use a **DeferredResult** here, which spring will do the filter in origin thread and filtering it again in a new thread. If you set log level to Debug, you will notice log like this.

```
15:14:06.948 [http-nio-8199-exec-5] DEBUG o.s.s.w.h.writers.HstsHeaderWriter - Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match the requestMatcher org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter$SecureRequestMatcher@efe6068
15:14:06.948 [http-nio-8199-exec-5] DEBUG o.s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
15:14:06.948 [http-nio-8199-exec-5] DEBUG o.s.b.w.f.OrderedRequestContextFilter - Cleared thread-bound request context: org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@163cab73
15:14:07.148 [http-nio-8199-exec-6] DEBUG o.s.b.w.f.OrderedRequestContextFilter - Bound request context to thread: SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper[ FirewalledRequest[ org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest@42f1262]]
```

In a word, **it's executed once in one thread, but here're two threads.**

As I digged the google, I found there's no good solution.
If you have something like auth in request, a walk around way is add 
    **security.filter-dispatcher-types=REQUEST, ERROR**
Then the new thread(async one) will not get the security context. You need to check it and stop the filter chain inside it.

Or you just use the tranditional sync call like:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String test() {
    return "blank";
}
```

I found another helpful answer. https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-12608

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

Inside preHandle method, If you have response.sendError(<>, <>), then this preHandle method will execute twice for each API request. So remove sendError() method to execute this only once.

```
@Override
public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
    response.sendError(401, "Token is invalid");
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The prehandle method of the AsyncHandlerInterceptor will always be executed twice in async processing.